# How can I show NSLogs from apportable android emulator in console?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apportable

I am running my app which I ported using apportable (on Mac) on an android emulator. I know that NSLogs can be logged when using apportable on a physical device using the following command.

```
apportable log | grep AppName
```

I would like to log the NSLogs in the console when running the app on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The command you listed:

```
apportable log | grep AppName
```

works for both physical devices and for the emulator for me.

Here are some of the causes I have run into when using apportable and the android emulator:

1. In theory you can support multiple devices simultaneously, but sometimes I have noticed that you need to restart the android debug bridge when moving between a physical device and the emulator:

```Bash
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

2. Occasionally, repeated app installations or debugging seasons throw the emulator into a confused state and I rebuild it via:

```Bash
rm -r ~/.android/avd/AVD*
android avd # Run the virtual device manager and recreate a virtual device from a device definition
emulator -avd virtual-device-name -shell # NB: first run after a rebuild takes longer - should wait before attempting "apportable debug" or "apportable install"
adb logcat # or apportable log
```

3. I also like to clean the apportable device cache after an emulator rebuild or when swapping devices via:

```Bash
apportable clean_device_cache
```